# JAX-WS unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I have a stand-alone java app that creates services using Java JAX-WS.  I would like to create test cases to test the services, how can I go about that?

I thought about using an external client, outside the project, is this the best method?

Comment: *Did you mean... [tag:jax-ws]?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments about integration vs unit tests could go on and on. Just removing the web service layer and testing the inner business logic does not change an integration test into a unit test.

IMHO web services are a public API into your application, and you need them to work consistently between versions of your app. Therefore I would recommend an extensive  soapUI test suite, hitting your app and db as if it were a regular client. You can add assertions to check for expected success and failure messages (don't forget to test what your web services do when incorrect data is thrown at them). Also you can add groovy asserts to check your database state after each web service call.

I would fully recommend quick-running unit tests to complement the above, but getting a robust integration suite running every night against your overnight build will ensure the quality of your API and avoid many problems which would otherwise only be flushed out when your customers start hitting your services when your app has been deployed .

It is the nature of web services that they have no UI so are not well-tested if left to human testers.

Comment: This is what I was asking, I want to create something that will verify the service is functional, not just unit tests.

Comment: Yes I don't think you can rely on unit tests. Web services have their own challenges such as elements being missing, elements being marked as "xsi:nil", elements containing invalid data (string data when they should be int, etc). I couldn't recommend soapUI enough for testing Web Services, I have found it invaluable.

Comment: Link for those interested.  http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/getting-started.html

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, deploying a web service and testing it is an integration test, not a unit test. With that said, it's probably better to unit test this. I would make a separate layer that implements the business logic, and other layer that exposes it as a web service. Then you can test the business logic, without having to worry about the web service.

After all, you probably don't want to bother re-testing the web framework you are using to start up a web service. You really want to test your business logic. This will let you create faster and less brittle tests.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I would test the actual web service endpoint or the client.  I would move all of the business logic into some service layer and then unit-test those objects.  For example:

```
 @Path("/user")
 public class UserWebService {

   @Inject
   private UserService userService;

   @Path("/delete")
   public void deleteUser(@RequestParam long id) {
      userService.deleteUser(id);
   }

 }
```

Then I would unit test my UserService implementation.